# make window load wait for javascript injected content

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, load, window

I've built an app that pulls in content on document load and have noticed that window load seems to fire when the pages initial content has loaded. Is that the case? Is there some kind of boolean magic I can throw in to the window load event to make it wait until the initial content and new content has finished?

Here's what I'm working with

```
$doc.ready(function(){

    /* Pull in conditional content */
});
$win.load(function(){

    /* Fade page in once initial page content
    and conditional content have both loaded */
});
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you have to bind it to the loading of the window, rather than specifically to the loading of your content?

Comment: I've only ever done this stuff in `ready()`.  You can have many `ready()` blocks, so it's possible to have multiple partials in a template set their own blocks, and they'll all get called.

Comment: Rather use the callbacks from loading the dynamical content than `$win.load`, which waits for any ressources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> window load seems to fire when the pages initial content has loaded. Is that the case?

Yes, the `window.onload` event fires when the DOM and all assets (images, CSS) are loaded.

> Is there some kind of boolean magic I can throw in to the window load event to make it wait until the initial content and new content has finished?

No, there's no such magic. I suggest you fade your page in from the callback of the operation that loads the dynamic content.